# Heroku local server not starting

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a node/angular project which I have deployed on heroku.  I have come across a problem where local server will not start.  When I fire the command `heroku local` it gives me a warning `[WARN] No ENV file found` and then does nothing for a while.  After 2-3 minutes I get this error:

```
10:38:45 AM web.1 |  { [MongoError: server ds019038-a.mlab.com:19038 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ETIMEDOUT"}]
10:38:45 AM web.1 |    name: 'MongoError',
10:38:45 AM web.1 |    message: 'server ds019038-a.mlab.com:19038 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ETIMEDOUT"}' }
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
10:38:45 AM web.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

I have tried to run other heroku projects locally (which i know work) and I get the same issue with all of them. I have also tried running `node server.js` and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The command `heroku local` expects a `.env` file.  The warning you mention suggests that you've either not provided one, it's not in the expected directory, or perhaps it's formatted incorrectly so `heroku local` doesn't recognize it as such.

It seems likely you'll need to create a `.env` file with some configuration associated with MongoDB.  If successful, you should see:

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
```

Heroku will not issue the warning anymore, but if you don't have the right configuration in the file, I suspect MongoDB still will raise an error.  You can look at [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-mongodb-with-a-node-application-on-heroku) for detailed instructions on this.

Comment: When I run the command I still get `[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format` but it ends up with `Exited with exit code null` and no error. Any ideas?